# add image map script to post

Tags: posts, editor

when i add this script to my post html editor :

```
<div style="text-align:center; width:1100px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<img id="wordlmap" src="http://giftsforfriendsabroad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/worldmap-1024x449.png" usemap="#wordlmap" border="0" width="1100" height="489" alt="" />
<map id="wordlmap" name="wordlmap">
<area shape="rect" coords="845,267,929,324" href="/australia" alt="australia" title="australia"/>
</map>
</div>
```

after updating post, i only get:

```
<div style="text-align:center; width:1100px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<img id="wordlmap" src="http://giftsforfriendsabroad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/worldmap-1024x449.png" usemap="#wordlmap" border="0" width="1100" height="489" alt="" />

</div>
```

can someone help me please, thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The post content is filtered by [kses](http://ottopress.com/2010/wp-quickie-kses/), but you can extend the list of allowed tags. A [search in the plugin directory for kses](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=kses) shows some useful results.

Try [Extend KSES](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/extend-kses/), it seems to be exactly what you need (I haven’t tested it):

> This plugin extends the HTML functionalify of the WordPress kses.php file, which states the allowable HTML that the post/page content editor will accept.
>   It allows the site administrator to check pre-defined HTML tags that can also be allowed via the editor. Tags include: `object`, `embed`, `param`, `iframe`, **`map`** and extensions have been added to the `div` and `img` tags.